# R regex to find two words same string, order and distance may vary

Tags: regex, r

I want to create a single regex (if possible) to search through strings and determine if two words occur in the same string.  I know I can use two `grepl` statements (as seen below) but am wanting to use a single regex to test for this condition.  The more efficient the regex the better.

I want to find strings that contain both "man" and "dog" case insensitive.

```
x <- c(
    "The dog and the man play in the park.",
    "The man plays with the dog.",
    "That is the man's hat.",
    "Man I love that dog!",
    "I'm dog tired"
)

## this works but I want a single regex
grepl("dog", x, ignore.case=TRUE)  & grepl("man", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr You don't have a `gerpl` function :-)

Comment: I _am_ beginning to think there is one somewhere in some package tho (ref: https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1849479-6035326254826213377) :-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr added a comment to that `grepl("\\bat\\b", f, perl=T)`

Comment: Nice. I still have no idea why ppl post code things to LI. Worst platform ever for it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use regex alternation operator `|`.

```
grepl(".*(dog.*man|man.*dog).*", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Use word boundaries if necessary..

```
grepl(".*(\\bdog\\b.*\\bman\\b|\\bman\\b.*\\bdog\\b).*", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

No need for leading and trailing `.*`

```
grepl("(dog.*man|man.*dog)", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

You may give the case-insensitive modifier within the regex itself.

```
grepl("(?i)(dog.*man|man.*dog)", x)
```

Comment: Hey! Is there a way to write an expression, where I can define the number of words that can exist between 'dog' and 'man' (in that order)? @Avinash

Answer (score 6):

You can use a Perl-like regex with 2 look-aheads:

```
grepl("^(?=.*\\bman\\b)(?=.*\\bdog\\b)", x, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/aXIHQe)

Results for the input above: `[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

The `^(?=.*\\bman\\b)(?=.*\\bdog\\b)` lookaheads just check for whole words `man` and `dog` in the input, and only pass if both are present, irrespective of their order (`dog` may be before `man`, or vice versa).

Due to the `^` start-of-string anchor, these checks are performed only once per input, thus, keeping performance on a good level.