# PCRE Regex (*COMMIT) equivalent for Python

Tags: python, regex

The below pattern took me a long time to find. When I finally found it, it turns out that it doesn't work in Python. Does anyone know if there is an alternative?

`(*COMMIT)` Defined: Causes the whole match to fail outright if the rest of the pattern does not match.

`(*FAIL)` doesn't work in Python either. But this can be replaced by `(?!)`.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|Pattern:                                       |
|^.*park(*COMMIT)(*FAIL)|dog                    |
+-------------------------------------+---------+
|Subject                              | Matches |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|The dog and the man play in the park.|  FALSE  |
|Man I love that dog!                 |  TRUE   |
|I'm dog tired                        |  TRUE   |
|The dog park is no place for man.    |  FALSE  |
|park next to this dog's man.         |  FALSE  |
+-------------------------------------+---------+
```

Example taken from:
[regex match substring unless another substring matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747887/regex-match-substring-unless-another-substring-matches/39795732#39795732)

Comment: You can do `r"^(?!.*park)(?=.*dog)(.*)"` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qDQDG/1)

Comment: That regex doesn't work in PCRE, either; the answer you adapted it from is wrong.  But never mind control verbs, lookaheads work fine in both flavors, as [Sebastian's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39796696/20938) demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be a generic replacement, but for your case you can work with lookaheads, to assert that dog is matched, but park is not: `^(?=.*dog)(?!.*park).*$`

Your samples on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gOY9GT/1)

Comment: This worked, albiet it's very slow when iterating over a lot of data, but it works. I think the multiple .* is what's slowing it down.

Comment: Update: Well, I don't think your example is slow. I'm trying to add multiples, ^(?=.*dog|.*cat|.*bird)(?!.*park|.*pool|.*trail).*$ That's what slowing it down. I'm sure.

Comment: Disregard. I had an error in a loop. This solution worked perfectly for me.