# Match string between a specific word and paired brackets after it with a single nested level support with an exception

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-look-ahead

I've a problem with a regex match. I need to find a specific substring in a string. Some examples:

```
1. IF[A != B; C[0]; D] ==> IF[A != B; C[0]; D]
2. IF[A != B; IF[E < F; ...; ...]; D] ==> IF[E < F; ...; ...]
3. IF[A != B; C; D] ==> IF[A != B; C; D]
```

So, I have this regula expression: `IF\[([^\[\]]*)\]`. It work fine in case 2 and 3, but in case 1 there is `C[0]` that contains square brackets.

I tried to change my regex in this way: `IF\[((?!IF))\]` and finaly `IF\[(.+(?!IF))\]`. I added a look ahead to say it "keep the IF that does not contains another IF". Now it works in case 1 and 3 but case 2 returns entire string.

How can I create a correct look head to solve this problem? I need to find the most internal IF in the string that can be the entire string.

I alredy tried with solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747960/5731129

Comment: Did you mean to write it as `IF\[((?:(?!IF\[).)*)\]` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/1))? However, it is not the right way to obtain matches with paired nested brackets. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Is it in R, JS, C#?

Comment: What I need is to find most internal IF, replace it and then reapply the regex on the result. All this to convert string in valid javascript if else code. So I use it in JS. Your solutions works pretty good (it keep ] in group) but in this case `IF[A != B; IF[A != C; IF[A != D; 0; 1]; 2]; 3]` not. I obtain `A != D; 0; 1]; 2]; 3`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've changed your regex in this way: `IF\[((?:(?!IF)[^\]])*)\]`. In this way it works correctly in all cases except case 1 (https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/2)

Comment: Try `IF\[([^][]*(?:(?<!\bIF)\[[^][]*][^][]*)*)]`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this solution works perfectly. Now I'll study the solution to understand all single parts. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match `IF[...]` substrings where the string between square brackets may contain another pair of square brackets unless preceded with an `IF`, with just a single nested bracket level.

For that, you may use

```
IF\[([^][]*(?:(?<!\bIF)\[[^][]*][^][]*)*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/3)

**Details**

- `IF\[` - an `IF[` substring
- `([^][]*(?:(?<!\bIF)\[[^][]*][^][]*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `(?:(?<!\bIF)\[[^][]*][^][]*)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

    - `(?<!\bIF)\[`  - a `[` char that is not immediately preceded with a whole word  `IF` (`\b` is a word boundary)
    - `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
    - `]` - a `]` char
    - `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: A little issue. Firefox doesn't support look behind. How can I fix it with look ahead?

Comment: @erikscandola  There is no pretty way then. Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/4) or [this one](https://regex101.com/r/GcCgok/5).

Comment: Works fine in every case. Thank you!